# Share class between front and back (nuxt.js)

Tags: module, export, default, nuxt.js

I 'm trying to share a simple class between vue and express.
The problem is that vue supports es6 import/export default, whereas express(node) only supports the require/module.exports syntax.

Is there a way to use export default statement in nuxt.js backend (express.js), so I can use my class in both ends? Or maybe, add support for module.exports in vue?

Thanks!

Comment: You could also transpile your server code, then you could use ES6 or the server too

Comment: With babel, this doesn't seem to be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can exlude you file from transpiler.

```
const Path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build:{
    extend({ module: { rules } }) {
      const rule = findJsxRule(rules)
      rule.exclude = exclude(
        [
          Path.resolve(__dirname, '../lib'),
          Path.resolve(__dirname, '../interface')
        ],
        rule.exclude
      )
    }
  }
}

function findJsxRule(rules) {
  return rules.find(rule => {
    return rule.test.toString() === '/\\.jsx?$/i'
  })
}

function exclude(paths, old) {
  return file => {
    if (paths.some(path => file.startsWith(path))) {
      return true
    } else if (old) {
      return old(file)
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```